# How do I initialize a map in street view mode using react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I've implemented the default react-google-map component and it is displaying the map correctly. However, is there a way to initialize it into street view with a given coordinate?

Original code I would like to modify below:

```
const Map = compose(
  withProps({
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={18}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: props.coord.lat, lng: props.coord.lng }}
  >
    {true && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: props.coord.lat, lng: props.coord.lng }} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shared codesandbox for streetViewPanorama. But you need to add your API key in map url.
codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/147kvk67zj

Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Thanks Sakhi! That's really helpful. Is there any way to point the camera to the coordinates? E.g. Have the camera facing where you have placed the OverlayView when the Street View loads?

Comment: Nevermind, found that you can add the options with a heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={api}>
  <GoogleMap
    mapContainerStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
    center={center}
    zoom={10}
    options={options}
  >
    <StreetViewPanorama position={center} visible={true}/>
  </GoogleMap>
</LoadScript>
```